# Making a GUI for receiving/checking user input - how to arrange GUI and validation checks

Tags: design, design-patterns, architecture, object-oriented-design, gui

Sorry if my question sounds general, I'm new to GUI and frontend/backend ideas and all that (mostly I just do scripts for math hw and such) but I make it more specific here. I have a program that runs through various processes (A -> B -> C -> etc), where each process depends on different user inputs. So here's what I think is needed:

1. A [notebook](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/complex.html#notebook) where each page has parameters for each process, and the user can submit their inputs.
2. Instant checks as the user inputs parameters - if they select something and a new option becomes available, or if they put in a bad character so an error pops up - all of these should occur immediately, which Tkinter allows with function calls when values change.
3. And finally, I also want the user to be able to load input files and have the contents be checked, presumably with the same functions used by the GUI, but not necessarily through the GUI; that is, if it's just being checked, this could be done through the command line

So my question is: what are the design principles I should follow for this? I'm thinking:

1. A top-level Input_GUI.py class that gets pages based on what parts of the process the input wants to run.
2. Each Process/Page should have a class that just organizes the widgets on the page, e.g. A_page.py, B_page.py. Each widget will have a function call to the appropriate function for checking, so -
3. Each process/page should also have a class with functions that check the input parameters, e.g. A_checks.py
4. As for users being able to load/check input files, maybe this would mean the Page classes would have a constructor that would accept an input file and set the parameters, then have the Page class also call the Checks?
5. If the user wants to check input files on the command line, the Page class could print out any errors that occurred?

To figure out the correct approach, I looked for open-source software that might have similar things pop up - FileZilla had some similar GUIs for inputs, and I think they have all their function checks in cpp files like this one ([manual_transfer.cpp](https://svn.filezilla-project.org/filezilla/FileZilla3/branches/3.41.x/src/interface/manual_transfer.cpp?revision=9139&view=markup)), but not sure where the GUI details are (I'm not very familiar with C++). The TkDocs also showed a small example of a Query Dialog (under section [Idle Dialogs](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/idle.html#idledialogs)), where they include the validation check as part of the widget function. Is this the way to go? Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

## What is validation?

Its a border guard between the unruly, disordered mess out there, and the nice well-behaved order in here.

There are a lot of borders.

- There is the border between the keyboard on the input control.
- The border between the input control and the ui code accessing its value.
- The borders between various parts of the UI, as the data is passed around.
- The border between the UI code and the domain model.
- The border between two different states of the domain model.
- The border between the domain model and the data store.

And borders operate in both directions. *The UI isn't necessarily happy with the mess that is the domain model.*

So where is the best place to put validation? *At the borders, it certainly isn't going to help at a none border.*

---

Okay, but practically what should I do? *Okay, down to brass tacks...*

You should put validation that is reasonably enforceable on a given border.

Taking your input box example:

It would make sense to setup a regex for accepting data in a given format in the control itself (presuming it permits that). This way numbers are numbers, email addresses atleast have an @ in them, and text doesn't contain unexpected and delightful unicode compliant hieroglyphs.

This way the control will pass data on in atleast some limited (though still largely unknown state). At this point it makes sense to enforce some more validations. The controller (assuming you are using MVC for modelling your UI) knows more about what kind of data this should be. For example if is a number that it is larger than `X`, smaller than `Y`, and has `K` or less decimal places.

The controller might even attempt a reasonable error recovery if the data was bad. Like clamping it to the largest or smallest value, or rounding off extra decimal places and updating the ui.

Eventually the controller is happy with the data (humans will eventually fix it, we hope) and it'll be passed down to the model, though hopefully it has been converted from a string to a more specific type like `EmailAddress`, `Int`, etc...

The model itself should enforce further validations, this might mean reinforcing the same constraints again (such as min, max, and precision). No one said you should trust even your own controllers. When you change code in future you may forget some of these checks. Besides the model is validating to ensure its a good model, the controller is validating to provide a better user experience - two different goals.

Anyway, the model actually has more knowledge than the controller. Namely it knows about the domain, or at least the display domain if the M in MVC means View-Model and not Domain-Model. In which case it can pull several pieces of information together for example that number might be part of a series of numbers, and that series might have the requirement of being monotonically decreasing. With this greater context we can enforce this requirement.

Placing the check for monotonically decreasing values in the input control would not make sense, it would require too much knowledge about the system, and would make your application brittle. Imagine the next requirement update that flips the monotonically decreasing to monotonically increasing. you would have to update numerous text boxes.

Hopefully this helps, I understand it is pretty vague, but must architectural discussions are without an actual problem to solve.